# JQuery & AJAX get text instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table and it performs a calculation before sumbitting so I need to have values. But I want to submit the text from the options instead of the values although each time it submits the value. I have ried a number of differnet things but none seem to work. I think it may be something simple.

Create table:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_name[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_name" size="16" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_quantity[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" name="item_unit[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_unit" /></td>';
  //NEW ONES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  html += '<td><select name="item_glass[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_glass"><option>Select Glass Type</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_splash[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_splash"><option value="0">Select Splash</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box3($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" value="-" name="item_colour[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_colour" /></td>';

  html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" oninput="calc();calcSub()" name="item_HQuan[]" class="form-control item_HQuan" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_HDiam[]" oninput="calc();calcSub()" class="form-control item_HDiam"><option value="0">Select Hole Diameter</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box2($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="number" min="0" value="0" oninput="calc();calcSub()" name="item_CQuan[]" class="form-control item_CQuan" /></td>';

  //Total
  html += '<td><input type="text" value="0.0" name="item_Total[]" id="item_Total[]" class="form-control item_Total" readonly/></td>';


  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">Delete Item<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });
```

Fill options:

```
  $output .= '<option val="'.$row["glass_type"].'" value="'.$row["glass_price"].'">'.$row["glass_type"].'</option>';
```

Sumbit values:

```
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';

  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == 0)
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == 0)
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == 0)
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });


  $('.item_glass').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).text() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
```

...

```
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  console.log(form_data);

  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
       // window.location.replace("saved_quotes.php?success");
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });
```

This always returns the values of over the text entry even when the val() is set to text(). Is their anyway of fixing this?

Comment: Why do you have val="" and value=""?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.text()** will get the HTML text from an item. That would return the entire form control object/text without html. You will need to still look for **.val()** for a  input field.